# How to concat column using myng'sql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using following,

```
select * , CONCAT_WS( row1.',' , combined_data) AS  combined_data from table
```

Actually i looking the data like

```
row1 Value , row2 Value , row3 Value, ..
```

Please help me to resolve my problem

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this..

```
select * , CONCAT_WS( ',',column_name1,colimn_name2) AS  combined_data from table
```

The syntax for CONCAT_WS is

```
CONCAT_WS (separator, string1, string2,…)
```

Which is  is used to join two or more strings with a separator.